# Redundant import of Packages in a Java project - Is there any performance impact?

Tags: java, spring, performance

In my java project, during the process of refactoring my code, I see a lot of redundant packages. Eclipse marks them in light yellow as shown in the image below

[image]

What is the suggested practice of handling hese ? Do these redundant packages have any performance impact and if yes, would be interested in knowing how.

Comment: It has 0 impact at runtime. Imports don't exist at runtime. They're just a convenience for you, the developer, to be able to use simple class names rather than fully qualified class names in the source code. The byte code doesn't use imports.

Comment: Thanks - that makes it clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In eclipse there's a handy shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>o</kbd> which will organize your imports and remove unused.

Unused imports have a trivial impact on the compiler. It's not a big deal however it's distracting and best practice is to remove them.
Also it's prefered to use imports like this

```
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.List;
```

over this

```
import java.util.*;
```

using star will import all packages from util which you don't need in most scenarios...

Comment: thanks for that. My only problem with ctrl+shift+o  is that it is not very smart when conflicting packages are present and there are situations where this can cause problems. I prefer to manually add. But i take your point that it can be useful in removing redundant packages. That is a good idea.